# SQL: CREATE PROCEDURE and CALL PROCEDURE

Tags: sql

Can someone look at SQL code below and give me a hint what wrong is with the code?

I created a procedure, if it exists replaced with the current one, that takes a id_id parameter as an integer and a input_num parameter as an integer. Inside SQL statement the table updates the input_num field in the table for the identified by id_id to the value in the input_num parameter.

When I am calling the stored procedure, I get an error

> Value of id_id is too long

though it should be not an issue here, I think. I tried to replace the value, but in this case the dataset is empty.

My code:

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE UPDATE_NUMBER 
     (IN id_id INTEGER, 
      IN input_num INTEGER)
LANGUAGE SQl
MODIFIES SQL DATA 

BEGIN

        IF input_num > 80 AND input_num < 99 THEN
             UPDATE chicago
             SET outcome = 'VeryStrong'
             WHERE id_id = id;
        ELSEIF input_num > 60 AND input_num < 79 THEN
             UPDATE chicago
             SET outcome  = 'Strong'
             WHERE id_id  = id; 
        ELSEIF input_num > 40 AND input_num < 59 THEN
             UPDATE chicago
             SET outcome = 'Average'
             WHERE id_id = id; 
        ELSEIF input_num  > 20 AND input_num  < 39 THEN
             UPDATE chicago
             SET outcome = 'Weak'
             WHERE id_id = id; 
        ELSEIF input_num  > 0 AND input_num < 19 THEN
             UPDATE chicago
             SET outcome = 'VeryWeak'
             WHERE id_id = id; 
        ELSE 
            UPDATE chicago
            SET outcome = outcome
            WHERE id_id = id;
            
        END IF;

END
@
```

609993 is id and 50 is entered value to check.

```
CALL UPDATE_NUMBER (609993, 50)
```

I appreciate any feedback.

AKA

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? AFAICT this is IBM Db2 (or "DB2" or "DB/2" depending on your IBM salesperson...), if so, exactly what edition and version of Db2 is this?

Comment: You don't need a `PROCEDURE` for this - you can reduce your entire procedure down to a single `UPDATE` statement with a `CASE`-expression in the `SET` clause, btw (as opposed to your current approach of having _separate_ `UPDATE` statements in `IF` branches).

Comment: @Dai I am using IBM Db2

Comment: Yes, but what edition and version?

Comment: @Dai On the IBM platform. I think there is not any information about edition.

Comment: @Dai  here is a line of code I used  according to you: UPDATE chi_schools SET Leaders_Icon = CASE WHEN Leaders_Score > 80 AND Leaders_Score < 99  THEN Leaders_Icon = 'VeryStrong' WHEN Leaders_Score > 60 AND Leaders_Score < 79 THEN Leaders_Icon = 'Strong' (..etc..)  WHEN Leaders_Score > 0 AND Leaders_Score < 19  THEN Leaders_Icon = 'VeryWeak'  END  WHERE Leaders_Score IN (50, 70, 30);   
But it is displaying me an error: replace to Vertical_Bar.   I am confused now. Any ideas?

Comment: "On the IBM platform" is not a helpful designation. How can you not know if you're running on Z/OS or x86 or POWER (for example)? Is this on-prem, localhost, IBM Cloud, AWS, etc?

Comment: Also, we need the `CREATE TABLE` definition of your `chicago` table.

Comment: @Dai, In this case, this is not an answer to my question. Nevertheless thanks!

Comment: I wasn't giving you an answer to your question - my earlier remark about `UPDATE` was just a general code-quality improvement suggestion. I still need to know what edition you're running because different editions and versions of Db2 have different functionality, sometimes radically different.

Comment: @Dai, I am running Db2 on IBM cloud.